# How can I efficiently remove unnecessary whitespace from XML files with a Linux or PHP command?

Tags: xml, linux

I am looking for an efficient way to reduce the size of my XML files with a Linux or PHP command by removing unnecessary whitespace.
I cannot use compression as an external process only accepts uncompressed files.

I am looking for something like `sed -i 'xxx' file.xml` for example. 
Even two separate commands (one to remove spaces and the other to remove carriage return) are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use **sed**, you can do the same (trim lines) and concatenate these lines as above with these two commands:

```
sed -i -e '/^ */s///' -e '/ *$/s///' file.xml # remove leading blanks and trailing blanks
sed -i -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta' file.xml   # remove carriage return
```

As you can see, I put a space between two lines I concatenate for the case you have a text node on several lines in order to avoid the last word on a line would be concatenated with the first word on the next line. For deleting the newlines without inserting a blank, change the command of the second **sed** from `s/\n/ /` into `s/\n//`.

Comment: @JilanA. Do you have an alternative solution? The author seems to ask a **sed** command with the option *-i*.

Comment: Hello, I am the author, I though sed would be fast enough, the only constraint I have is I am on a linux server an I use PHP as programming language. The second sed took more than an hour for an xml file of 725Mo. I will try to use the php solution.

Comment: If the second **sed** command runs too slow, try with **perl** issuing `perl -pi -e 's/\n/ /' file.xml`...

Answer (score 0):

Just trim each line. This will remove whitespaces at begin and end.

```php
$newFile = [];

$lines = file('./your.xml');
foreach($lines as $line) {
   $line = trim($line);
   if(!empty($line)) $newFile[] = $line;
}

file_put_contents('./yourClean.xml', join(PHP_EOL, $newFile));
```